# Understanding てもってね

Tags: grammar, manga

A guy has a girlfriend who usually goes out for a whole day for training and arrives late. But on a day before 本番, she arrives early. He asked what happened and she said

> まあ本番前日に根詰め過ぎてもってね

I don't understand what てもってね means here. It seems to mean "we should rest before the big day."

Answer (score 1):

A lot is omitted.

It means 本番前日に詰め込みすぎても(良くない)ってね(一般に言われてるよね).

In English, ”(It is generally said that it's not good) to cram too much the day before the performance.”

So it is 詰め込みすぎても/ってね rather than 詰め込みすぎ/てもってね.